# Stargate Atlantis Boxsets

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

I am wanting to purchase a Stargate Atlantis boxset, however there seem to be two to choose from
There is a 'megapack' [as shown here](http://www.videoezy.com.au/DVD/stargate-atlantis-season-1-5-megapack/dp/179120)

And there is a 'Complete pack' [as shown here](http://www.videoezy.com.au/DVD/stargate-atlantis-season-1-5-complete/dp/178811)

**My question is what is the difference between these two sets?** Are there differences in content other than special features and making-of videos?

Comment: Looks like the difference is $154

Comment: It's had to say, both have 26 discs and look the same apart form the packaging. I suspect the *megapack* to be the a package of the *original* Season boxes, (the 5 Season boxes warped together in a bigger box to make a pack) while Complete pack would be a box with a unified design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Megapack is a more recent release (re-released in 20/6/2012 as opposed to 29/7/2009 for the Complete).

TV studios often re-release TV series on DVD, usually in different/cheaper packaging.

The Megapack looks like my DVD boxset, I'll check tonight.

Comment: If it is, is each season in its own DVD case in the pack?

Comment: Yes, each season's in it's own plastic box with hinged plastic holders inside for each disc.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ill just grab the mega pack as it's cheaper!